# Why is self not defined in my program

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, attributes, typeerror

The first part of the program defines the class and the second part calls on the class though a different program as it follows but I keep getting a "TypeError: check_mood() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' " for line 5 in the second part
import random

```
class Animal:
    #initialize attributes
    def __init__(self,animal_type, name, mood):
        self.__animal_type = animal_type
        self.__name = name
        self.__mood = mood

    # set methods
    def set_animal_type(self, animal_type):
        self.__animal_type = animal_type

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_mood(self, mood):
        self.__mood = mood

    #check mood
    def check_mood(self):
        integer = random.randint(1,3)
        if integer == 1:
            self.__mood = "happy"
        elif integer == 2:
            self.__mood = "hungry"
        elif integer == 3:
            self.__mood = "sleepy"


    #return methods
    def get_animal_type(self):
        return self.__animal_type

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_mood(self):
        return self.__mood
```

And I made a simple test program to run it through:

```
import Animal

an = input("enter aninal:")
na = input("enter name:")
mo = Animal.Animal.check_mood()

animals = Animal.Animal(an,na,mo)

print(animals.get_animal_type(), animals.get_name(), animals.get_mood())
```

Comment: `Animal.Animal.check_mood()` you're trying to call an *instance* method without an instance.   You need to use an instance, e.g. `a = Animal(); a.check_mood()`

Comment: i did this and received the error "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Comment: @helpplease, it needs to be Animal.Animal() to get the class within the module. Modules are usually better named lowercase.

Comment: I tried that as well and received an error saying that I was missing 3 required positional arguments

Comment: @helpplease, you wrote this code yourself. It takes three arguments. You called `Animal.Animal()` and the interpreter responded 'Missing 3 required positional arguments.' What do you think is wrong?

Comment: The only idea I had was having to write Animal.Animal(animal_type, name, mood) within my second program but when doing this I received the error that animal_type was not defined

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to run a class method without instantiating your class first:

```
Animal.Animal.check_mood()
```

This will not work, unless check_mood() is a class method or a static method.

You need to instantiate your class and run your method on an instance

```
dog = Animal()
dog.check_mood()
```

or use a static method or a class method.

A static method is a function that does not receive an implicit first argument (like `self` in an instance method) and is thus just a regular function.

A class method is a function that receives the class itself, rather than an instance, as its first argument. This is usually only useful if you want to create an instance of a class from non-standard arguments. This is not likely be useful in this case, since you don't actually need the class within the method.

An example of how you would use a static method:

```
class Animal(object):
    @staticmethod
    def check_mood():
          #yourfunction
```

and a class method:

```
class Animal(object):
    @classmethod
    def check_mood(cls):
          #yourfunction
```

However, since you're talking about the mood of an animal, I'm assuming you want to instantiate an animal first, then check its mood.

Answer (score 1):

check_mood() is an instance method - it needs a particular animal whose mood it checks. But here

```
mo = Animal.Animal.check_mood()
```

You're asking for the mood of the Animal class itself. Instead, call it from `__init__` like this:

```
self.check_mood()
```

You would then delete the line giving you the current error, pass only two arguments to `Animal()`, and modify the `def __init__` line so that it no longer expects a mood (since the Animal itself generates it randomly).

Comment: the mood is supposed to be randomly generated from 3 choices, which is why I have check mood in the first part

Comment: @helpplease, if you need to generate the mood randomly, you can do it within the constructor. Call `Animal.check_mood` within `Animal.__init__` instead of passing `mood` as an argument to `Animal.__init__`.

Comment: I'm confused as to where that would be within the program. Sorry i'm just really confused by this!